# Do different Hamiltonians result in different ground states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, many-body, ground-state, density-functional-theory

I'm learning density functional theory. In the proof of Hohenberg–Kohn theorem I, we assume that different Hamiltonians result in different ground states. Is it true?

In general, for example, we can choose this Hamiltonian:
$$
H = \sum_{k}\epsilon_{k}n_{k} + \epsilon_d n_d
$$
If we assume that Fermi energy $\epsilon_F$ is smaller that $\epsilon_d$. Now we change $\epsilon_d$ and we get the same ground state.

So can we assume different Hamiltonians result in different ground states here? Here the Hamiltonian is:
$$
H=\frac{1}{2}\int\nabla\psi^{\dagger}(\boldsymbol{r})\nabla\psi(\boldsymbol{r})\,\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}+\int v(\boldsymbol{r})\psi^{\dagger}(\boldsymbol{r})\psi(\boldsymbol{r})\,\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}|}\psi^{\dagger}(\boldsymbol{r})\psi^{\dagger}(\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime})\psi(\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime})\psi(\boldsymbol{r})\,\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}^{\prime}
$$

We can change $v(\boldsymbol r)$.

Comment: No, a Hamiltonian $H$ has the same ground state (if existent) as $H+\lambda I$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. But this is not a problem in DFT/ Hohenberg-Kohn theorems. Rather, the theorems prove that for a given form of the Hamiltonian (i.e. $T$ and $W$ are fixed, only the potential $V$ changes with respect to different systems, as you also point out), there are no two external potentials which differ by more than a constant that lead to the same ground state. To reiterate: What you ask is what you prove in the theorems. Which source are you following?